# Grails Spring Security Core Plugin Vs. Grails Spring Security REST plugin

Tags: rest, grails, grails-plugin

The grails application, Which I am developing  will provide the REST  API's for the mobile application as well as it has it's own existence as a web application. I have never used any of the Plugin mentioned above. Can any one help me understand, which plugin will be more useful or in **which scenario which plugin should be used?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use Spring Security Rest without Spring Security Core. 
SSC gives you the securation of the application, and Spring Security Rest gives you the ability of securizing your rest requests throw the Spring Security Core to your application.

Answer (score 1):

We have used the REST plugin for securing rest services, for instance you have an AngularJS front end that makes calls to a grails backend. Core provides a login page in grails for instance.  You can use both plugins together, and the REST plugin may use CORE ... don't know off of the top of my head.